# https request on github.com subdomains return wrong 301 redirections to domain

Tags: https, subdomain, 301-redirect, github

First

When executing `curl -iv4 https://support.github.com/contact` I am receiving 301 responses with location `https://github.com/contact`.

Obviously when executing curl against the location returned from the 301 response, I am only getting a 404 response.

Some of my machines (linux hosts or docker containers) are never affected, some are.
For some reason it seems tied to my network.

I discovered the issue when trying to hit the api.github.com subdomain, the issue being the same.

I have opened a github support ticket with no answer for the moment.

The issue is the same in web browsers so it's not tied to curl at all.

So if anyone has any idea on what could cause a server to wrongly return a 301 response on https, I am open to any suggestion

EDIT:

Failing query

```
fail-host:~$ curl -iv4 https://support.github.com/contact
*   Trying 140.82.121.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to support.github.com (140.82.121.3) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.com
*  start date: Mar 25 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 30 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "support.github.com" matched cert's "*.github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert, Inc.; CN=DigiCert High Assurance TLS Hybrid ECC SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x5579f6dcac10)
> GET /contact HTTP/2
> Host: support.github.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 301
HTTP/2 301
< content-length: 0
content-length: 0
< location: https://github.com/contact
location: https://github.com/contact

<
* Connection #0 to host support.github.com left intact
```

Success query:

```
fail-host:~$ curl -iv4 https://support.github.com/contact
*   Trying 140.82.121.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to support.github.com (140.82.121.3) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.com
*  start date: Mar 25 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 30 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "support.github.com" matched cert's "*.github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert, Inc.; CN=DigiCert High Assurance TLS Hybrid ECC SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x5579f6dcac10)
> GET /contact HTTP/2
> Host: support.github.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 301
HTTP/2 301
< content-length: 0
content-length: 0
< location: https://github.com/contact
location: https://github.com/contact

<
* Connection #0 to host support.github.com left intact
```

EDIT: Fixed

The issue is on github.com end, see:

Will result in a wrong 301 redirection:
`curl -v https://support.github.com/contact --resolve 'support.github.com:443:140.82.121.3'`

Will result in a right 302 redirection:
`curl -v https://support.github.com/contact --resolve 'support.github.com:443:140.82.114.21'`

So far github hasn't answered my personal support ticket.

Comment: Chances are you've got a proxy somewhere on the way that's intercepting requests. Check the CA of the certificate you get for `api.github.com`

Comment: I have updated my post with both of the logs. Both certificates seem to have valid certificates from github.

Comment: Try faking the HTTP user-agent header field to match the successful ones in curl.

Comment: @JohnGreene : same behaviour. I also tried to set the user agent to "test" and the behaviour is still consistent on the different machines

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on github.com end, see:

Will result in a wrong 301 redirection: curl -v https://support.github.com/contact --resolve 'support.github.com:443:140.82.121.3'

Will result in a right 302 redirection: curl -v https://support.github.com/contact --resolve 'support.github.com:443:140.82.114.21'

So far github hasn't answered my personal support ticket.